# How to remove Windows 8 bootloader (or arrange for Grub not to detect it)

Tags: windows-8, bootloader, grub2

I have a dual-boot system with Windows 8 and Linux.  I have two Windows partitions: one 64-bit and one 32-bit.  The 64-bit partition is the one I wish to boot; the 32-bit partition is there as a backup of my old Windows XP files.

When I run `update-grub`, the `os-prober` finds *both* Windows 8 bootloaders.  I want it to find only the new, 64-bit bootloader.  Is there a way for me to overwrite the bootloader on the other partition, without harming the files?  Or is there a way to tell `update-grub` to ignore the partition labeled `WinX8bak`?

(I do not want to tell `update-grub` to ignore a particular device such as `/dev/sdd1` because the device numbers are not always consistent after boot.)

Comment: Have you tried adding `.bak` to the bootloader filename? You can easily revert it at any time.

Comment: Why not use a static grub.cfg file.   http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config